# TensorFlow: use tensor as list argument in graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to use a tf.Tensor as an argument of type (python) list for another operation in a TensorFlow graph.
In other words, I would like to use a Tensor as dynamic list argument for another operation. Is this possible?

Executable example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

graph = tf.Graph()
var1 = np.random.randn(2, 3)
var2 = np.random.randn(2, 3, 4)

with graph.as_default():
    def getRange(myTensor):
        myRank = tf.rank(myTensor)
        return tf.range(tf.constant(1), tf.squeeze(myRank))

    def getMoments(myTensor):
        myMoments = tf.nn.moments(myTensor, axes=getRange(myTensor))
        return myMoments
    var1tf = tf.Variable(var1)
    var2tf = tf.Variable(var2)
    var1moments = getMoments(var1tf)
    var2moments = getMoments(var2tf)
    rangeVar1 = getRange(var1tf)
    rangeVar2 = getRange(var2tf)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    sess.run([init])
    print(sess.run([rangeVar1])) # outputs [1], ok
    print(sess.run([rangeVar2])) # outputs [1, 2], ok
    print(sess.run([var1moments]))
    print(sess.run([var2moments]))
```

This throws:

```
raise TypeError("'Tensor' object is not iterable.")
```

Comment: Interesting question. Just for curiosity, for what kind of problem do you have to handle tensors of unknown rank?

Comment: I am using this code in a function that is called with tensors of different ranks

Comment: Updated my example to an executable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using get_shape():

```
def getMoments(myTensor):
    myRank = len(myTensor.get_shape().as_list())
    print('rank via shape:', myRank)
    myMoments = tf.nn.moments(myTensor, axes=list(range(1, myRank)))
    return myMoments
```